# How to make svg map hide info on area click

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Okay so i have an svg map that i made and my aim is to:

1. Have info displayed upon clicking each svg path.
2. When a different path is clicked hide the info of the last clicked path and show only the info of the path that was clicked.

I currently have the first of the 2 options working but i dunno how to get the old info to hide when another path is clicked...
The snippet i provided has only 3 but the full thing has about 30 paths just in case that info is needed.

Im a noob so if theres any way to improve the code feel free to share also :)

Here's a codepen with a little bit of it: https://codepen.io/aj-francis/pen/bGWppbm

```js
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var lot101 = document.getElementsByClassName('lot101')[0];
  var lot102 = document.getElementsByClassName('lot102')[0];
  var lot103 = document.getElementsByClassName('lot103')[0];

  lot101.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("lot-content")[0].style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementsByClassName('lot101-content')[0].style.display = 'block';
  });
  lot102.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("lot-content")[0].style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementsByClassName('lot102-content')[0].style.display = 'block';
  });
  lot103.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("lot-content")[0].style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementsByClassName('lot103-content')[0].style.display = 'block';
  });
});
```

```css
.path{
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.path:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.interactive-map{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding: 40px 30px;
}
.interactive-map .lot-info{
  width: 45%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
.interactive-map .svg-map{
  width: 50%;
}
.interactive-map .lot-info .lot-content{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="interactive-map">

<div class="lot-info">
<div class="lot-content lot101-content">
  <h1>Lot 101</h1>
  <h4>SQ-FT || SQ-M</h4>
  <h5>LOT PRICE</h5>
</div>
<div class="lot-content lot102-content">
  <h1>Lot 102</h1>
  <h4>SQ-FT || SQ-M</h4>
  <h5>LOT PRICE</h5>
</div>
<div class="lot-content lot103-content">
  <h1>Lot 103</h1>
  <h4>SQ-FT || SQ-M</h4>
  <h5>LOT PRICE</h5>
</div>
</div>

<div class="svg-map">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 947.38 652.28"><title>SB-Hills</title>

  <path class="path lot101" d="M232.74,704.06a79.87,79.87,0,0,1,16.69,20.65c7.37,1.9,54.57,14.17,66.4,19.43,4.14,1.84,5.23,1.31,5.24,1.31.22-.41-.17-2.38-1-4.05l-.13-.33-8.45-28.2-1.42-45.5.24-.47c11.57-23.18-5.59-35.94-6.33-36.47l-.22-.19-26.18-25-80.07,59.45Z" transform="translate(-62.62 -231.09)" fill="#222629"/>

  <polygon class="path lot102" points="50.38 347.82 114.11 418.27 184.34 354.22 182.41 353.02 154.41 299.75 50.38 347.82" fill="#222629"/>

  <path class="path lot103" d="M81,437.11l-12.49,43c-1.8,4.05-2.21,7.43-1.18,9.77a5.27,5.27,0,0,0,2.72,2.75l.59.2,28.74,36v9.57l120-32.57.07-.59,26-56.21c-36.17-13.33-115.73-42.54-127.27-46.26Z" transform="translate(-62.62 -231.09)" fill="#222629"/>



<!-- SVG PATHS, OUTLINES & TEXT -->
<!-- no styles or editing required past here until closing svg tag.. -->

</svg>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript all elements with same class wont get display none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27214330/javascript-all-elements-with-same-class-wont-get-display-none) Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43337605/924299).

Answer (score 0):

Applying the usual solution (looping through all elements with the same class name) to your code would be something like this:

```js
function popElem(el) {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('lot-content');
  for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  var clickedPath = el.target.className.baseVal.split("path").pop();
  document.getElementsByClassName(clickedPath + "-content")[0].style.display = 'block';
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('path');
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    var elem = elems[i];
    elem.addEventListener('click', function(elem) {
      popElem(elem);
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.path{
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.path:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.interactive-map{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding: 40px 30px;
}
.interactive-map .lot-info{
  width: 45%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
.interactive-map .svg-map{
  width: 50%;
}
.interactive-map .lot-info .lot-content{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="interactive-map">

<div class="lot-info">
<div class="lot-content lot101-content">
  <h1>Lot 101</h1>
  <h4>SQ-FT || SQ-M</h4>
  <h5>LOT PRICE</h5>
</div>
<div class="lot-content lot102-content">
  <h1>Lot 102</h1>
  <h4>SQ-FT || SQ-M</h4>
  <h5>LOT PRICE</h5>
</div>
<div class="lot-content lot103-content">
  <h1>Lot 103</h1>
  <h4>SQ-FT || SQ-M</h4>
  <h5>LOT PRICE</h5>
</div>
</div>

<div class="svg-map">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 947.38 652.28"><title>SB-Hills</title>

  <path class="path lot101" d="M232.74,704.06a79.87,79.87,0,0,1,16.69,20.65c7.37,1.9,54.57,14.17,66.4,19.43,4.14,1.84,5.23,1.31,5.24,1.31.22-.41-.17-2.38-1-4.05l-.13-.33-8.45-28.2-1.42-45.5.24-.47c11.57-23.18-5.59-35.94-6.33-36.47l-.22-.19-26.18-25-80.07,59.45Z" transform="translate(-62.62 -231.09)" fill="#222629"/>

  <polygon class="path lot102" points="50.38 347.82 114.11 418.27 184.34 354.22 182.41 353.02 154.41 299.75 50.38 347.82" fill="#222629"/>

  <path class="path lot103" d="M81,437.11l-12.49,43c-1.8,4.05-2.21,7.43-1.18,9.77a5.27,5.27,0,0,0,2.72,2.75l.59.2,28.74,36v9.57l120-32.57.07-.59,26-56.21c-36.17-13.33-115.73-42.54-127.27-46.26Z" transform="translate(-62.62 -231.09)" fill="#222629"/>

<!-- SVG PATHS, OUTLINES & TEXT -->
<!-- no styles or editing required past here until closing svg tag.. -->
</svg>
</div>
</section>
```

As you see adding event listener code in a loop is also possible so you can simply avoid having to deal with code addressing individual elements if their interactive function should work the same.

Note I've used some dereferencing of SVG elements to get proper class name of your text element to show. If you change the naming of your classes you will have to change the relevant code too.